# How to Pause audio in Exo MediaPlayer2 when other apps play audio/video?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I m using Exo Media Player 2.5.0 to stream audio from a remote source . i want to pause the audio when other apps play Audio/Video .

Comment: Listen for AudioFocus change .

Comment: Focus change works for Android Music player but for other apps like VLC Facebook its not working

Answer (score 0):

As ADM said, the only way to know if another app is going to play audio is by listening to audio focus changes (after requesting audio focus for your own app first, of course).

Aside from that, you're, unfortunately, at the mercy of the other app also playing nicely and it requesting audio focus when it wants to play.